# React on click on button calling only once and next click it is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am newly started learning react.I have a text field and button. And On click on button I am displaying some results(using other functional component for results) by calling graphql. but here the issue I am facing is button is only working once after that I cannot call graphql api again on clicking on button. I suspect some issue with showResults boolean variable only(which I am setting on click on button). could some one help me to identify issue.

```
    

    const [consumption, setConsumption] = React.useState(1500);
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false);
    const displayProducts = () => {
        setShowResults(true);
    };
    const handleConsumptionChange = (event) => {
        let consumptionEntered = event.target.value;
        setConsumption(consumptionEntered);

    };
    return (
        <div className="simple">
            <TextField
                label="Kwh"
                size="medium"
                value={consumption}
                onChange={handleConsumptionChange}
                variant="outlined"
            />


            <Button variant="contained" size="medium"
                    onClick={displayProducts}>Tarif finden</Button>

            {showResults && <ProductResults/>}
        </div>

    );
};
export default SimpleForm;
```

```
     ' And my results display functional component code is below'
```

````
const ProductResults = (props) => {
    let bookId = props.bookId;
    const GET_BOOK = gql`
        {
            bookById(id: "book-1") {
                id
                name
                pageCount
                author{
                    id
                    firstName
                    lastName
                }
            }
        }

    `;
    console.log("props set is ::{}", props.bookId);
    const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(GET_BOOK);
    if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
    if (error) return <div>Error :(</div>;
    return (
        <div className="Product Results">

            <dl>

                <dd><span>{data.bookById.id}</span></dd>
                <dd><span>{data.bookById.name}</span></dd>
                <dd><span>{data.bookById.pageCount}</span></dd>

                <dd>
                    <h4>author details</h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Author Id: {data.bookById.author.id}</li>
                        <li>First Name: {data.bookById.author.firstName}</li>
                        <li>Last Name: {data.bookById.author.lastName}</li>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductResults```
````

Comment: Once the state is set to true, it is always setting to true. So I guess there is no state change and no update. try setShowResults(false) after setConsumption

Answer (score 0):

It probably is calling every time you click the button, but the button click just calls `displayProducts` which sets `setShowResults(true)`.

You can either use `setShowResults(previous => !previous)` to turn it into a toggle, or you need to add a seperate "refresh" button/functionality to the `ProductResults` component.

Answer (score 0):

Once the state is set to 'true', it is always setting to true. So I guess there is no state change and no update. try setShowResults(false) after setConsumption

Comment: It kind of works but It is removing/hiding existing results on change of consumption. But the actual use case will be button should be clickable. and results should not hide instead new results should be overridden with old results.